# Error call javascript variable from php json_encode() because there is json label number

Tags: javascript, php, json

I get problem to call javascript variable from php `json_encode()`.
At javascript, i can't get array.length because there are labels `1:`.
I want `[res_tmp]` array get format like `[sample]` array (no label number array, example: `1:`, `2:`).
Thanks for your help.

Echo(false):

```
res_tmp: {
0: null,
1: {
name: "AAA",
sort: 1
},
2: {
name: "DDD",
sort: 2
}, 
...
```

Echo(i wish):

```
res_tmp: {
 null,
{
name: "AAA",
sort: 1
},
{
name: "DDD",
sort: 2
}, 
...
```

this is my code:

```
    $tmp = [

        [
         "name"  => "1.AAA",
         "sort"  => 1,
      ],[
         "name"  => "10.CCC",
         "sort"  => 10,
      ],[
         "name"  => "11.BBB",
         "sort"  => 11,
      ],[
         "name"  => "2.DDD",
         "sort"  => 2,
      ],[
         "name"  => "3.EEE",
         "sort"  => 3,
      ],
    ];


for ($i=0; $i < count($tmp); $i++) { 
    $res_tmp[ $tmp[$i]['sort'] ] = $tmp[$i];
}

$nul = [0,4,5,6,7,8,9,12];
for ($j=0; $j < count($nul); $j++) { 
  $res_tmp[ $nul[$j] ] = null;
}

$val = [
    "sample" => $tmp, 
    "res_tmp" => $res_tmp, 
];
echo json_encode($val);
// echo "<pre>",print_r($val),"</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO. Here is a javascript approach.

What you have here is **not an array** but a **JSON dict**, which is an **object**. You can get the length of it in JavaScript using Object.keys:

```
let keys = Object.keys(res_tmp);
```

This will get you the array of keys. You can iterate that and access the values. Like so:

```
let res_tmp = {
  0: null,
  1: {
    name: "AAA",
    sort: 1
  },
  2: {
    name: "DDD",
    sort: 2
  }
}
let keys = Object.keys(res_tmp);
let arr = [];
for (let j=0;j<keys.length;++j)
{
  let item = res_tmp[keys[j]];
  arr.push(item);
}
```

Now **arr** holds the echo you wish.